# How to bind the text in a textbox of a usercontrol into a textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I create a user Control textbox and i want to bind the textblock to what i type in the user control's textbox. I try some code, but it doesn't work. Anyone can teach me? Thanks

My userControl TextBox:

```
<Grid  Background="Silver" Style="{StaticResource EntryFieldStyle}"  Width="175" Height="25" Margin="0" >          
    <TextBox Name="watermarkTextBox" Background="Green"   />    
</Grid>
```

My xaml code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <UserControls:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="usernameArea"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=usernameArea Path=watermarkTextBox.Text}"  FontSize="13" Foreground="White"/> 
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2**: One way to do this is using a dependency property along with implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

What'll happen is that we'll fire a PropertyChangedEvent every time the textbox's text is changed.
The Window window will subscribe to this event by accessing WatermarkTextBox's WatermarkText dependency property.

Here's how it looks:

---

WatermarkTextbox.xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="watermarkTextBox" ...
         TextChanged="watermarkTextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

WatermarkTextbox.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class WatermarkTextBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WatermarkTextProperty", typeof(String),
        typeof(WatermarkTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public String WatermarkText
    {
        get { return watermarkTextBox.Text; }
        set { OnPropertyChanged("WatermarkText"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
     }
     private void watermarkTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
     {
           WatermarkText = this.watermarkTextBox.Text;
     }

}
```

[MainWindow].xaml:

```
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=usernameArea Path=WatermarkText}" .../>
```

Adding a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) essentially allows you to expose values in your user control for modification in XAML (as well as bindings, in general).

---

You might also want to change the `Foreground` (text color) property of the `TextBlock` to something darker than white, because, by default, the `Background` is white.

Comment: Did you change the foreground to black?

Comment: @0070 Sorry, forgot about dependency property stuff. I updated the solution with the answer. This worked for me.

Comment: oh,still doesn't work......my background is black in color, so the font will be visible. Can you explain what parameter should put in each of the argument of the dependencyProperty.register?

Comment: @0070 Gahh, sorry again. This is what I get for trying to code something too quickly. I was thinking the binding was the other way around. I'll post a working solution now.

Comment: @0070 That should do it. Sorry for all the edits. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but do i need to include any reference? Because the INotifyPropertyChanged and PropertyChangedEventHandler could not be found.

Comment: O right. Add "using System.ComponentModel;" to the top off your xaml.cs file